# POCO classes with foreignkey relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose, I have the the following 'create table' scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE userrole
(
    id varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    description text NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;

CREATE TABLE users
(
    id varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    pwd varchar(7) NOT NULL,
    userrole varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (userrole) REFERENCES userrole(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ;
```

How to specify the foreign key relation using POCO classes?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
  public class User
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string pwd { get; set; }
        public string userrole { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("roleId")]
        public int roleId { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class userrole
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }   
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With POCO classes you make a *navigation property* that is a plain C# reference to the other object. It is also a good idea to create a property for the foreign key, as in some cases you might want to set the association by ID, without having to load the entire referenced object.

This will give you tables that match the definition you have done, except:

- The casing, as I've used the C# name standard casing.
- The `varchar` type - C# strings are unicode so they are mapped to `nvarchar` in SQL. Using `varchar` should be seen as deprecated in an international world (I'm from Sweden I like our ÅÄÖ characters).
- The `text` type which is deprecated, it will be mapped to `nvarchar(max)` instead.

```
public class UserRole
{
  [Key]
  [Required]
  [StringLength(45)]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(45)]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
  [Key]
  [Required]
  [StringLength(45)]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(45)]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(45)]
  public string pwd { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(45)]
  public virtual string UserRole { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [ForeignKey("UserRole")]
  public virtual UserRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

The attributes are used to define the mapping in detail:
* `[StringLength(45)]` sets the column width. Without it you will get `nvarchar(max)` columns which cannot be part of indexes. That would make them impossible to use as primary keys.
* `[Key]` designates the column as primary key of the column.
* `[Required]` makes the column `NOT NULL`.

### Security Alert

I really hope that this is only an example, if you are actually designing a user login system you are exposing your users to severe security issues with the password handling. Passwords should never be stored in plain text, nor with encryption that can be decrypted (ask Adobe). The only acceptable password storage is salted hashes. With ASP.NET you don't have to do that yourself, there are built in providers like `SimpleMembership` and the newer ASP.NET Identity that takes care of the user handling for you.